# ios base page view controller value allocation

Tags: ios, subclassing

Im using a Base view controller for some other view controllers,

Im making it the base as I have 4 to 6 of other view controllers that will be showing the same label and image...

so I tried to make this base page and subClass the other ViewControllers,

my doubt is that if I leave the dealloc for the strings that contain the value for the label and other string, when dealloc is called for that page, then I get an exception

> pointer being freed was not allocated

but I dont want just to comment out the deallocs for the labels,

so What im i doing wrong, missing?

here the BasePage

```
#import "BasePage.h"
@implementation BasePage
@synthesize titleString = _titleString;
@synthesize justifyTitleString = _justifyTitleString;

- (void) dealloc {
[_titleString dealloc];      
[_justifyTitleString dealloc];
[super dealloc];
}
- (id)initWithParams:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)justifyTitle
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.titleString = title;
    self.justifyTitleString = justifyTitle;
}
return self;
 }
```

my app uses a navigation controller, 
so when I call a page i use:

```
   CentresVC *centresVC = [[[CentresVC alloc]initWithParams:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Centre  %d", indexPath.row]:@"center"]autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:centresVC animated:YES];
```

and pop the views when navigating back,

- So I have the doubt of when using

> ```
>  [_titleString dealloc];      
>    [_justifyTitleString dealloc];
> ```

where the pointer for those labels get saved?, and if i just commented out wich doesnt seem nice, would i get then a memory leak that would crash?

how to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: NEVER call another object's dealloc method (unless it's [super dealloc] in a destructor). Use -release instead.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, thanks so what do you mean, shall I call dealloc inside the BasePage, or in the CreatedVC for that Base Page?, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Richard said, you shouldn't be calling other objects' `dealloc` method. Ever.

If `titleString` and `justifyTitleString` are retained/strong properties, then this version below would work. Assuming that no other objects had retained `titleString` and `justifyTitleString`, their retain counts would go to 0, and their `dealloc` methods would be called automatically.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [_titleString release];      
    [_justifyTitleString release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This next option would work too, since the synthesized setter for a strong/retained property sends `release` to the old value of the property before assigning the new one. Also, this would be preferred if you had overridden your setter to do additional cleanup of the old value.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    self.titleString = nil;
    self.justifyTitleString = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Finally, if you were using ARC, and you didn't need additional cleanup like in the second case above, you wouldn't need to override `dealloc` at all. But if you did need to override `dealloc`, you would omit `[super dealloc]` since that would be provided automatically by the compiler.